# MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "undefined"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js, passport-local

I'm getting some trouble with my application right now...

so this is my models.js:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Beep = new mongoose.Schema({
    created_by: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    text: String
});


//declaration of models with respective schemas
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', User);
module.exports = mongoose.model('Beep', Beep);
```

I'm using passport for the authentication part and below is part of my passport-init.js

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = mongoose.model(User);
var LocalStrategy   = require('passport-local').Strategy;
var bCrypt = require('bcrypt-nodejs');


module.exports = function(passport){

    passport.serializeUser(function(user, result) {
        console.log('serializing user:', user._id);
        //return the unique id for the user (the default id provided by mongoDB)
        return result(null, user._id);
    });


    passport.deserializeUser(function(username, result) {

        User.findById(id, function(err, user){

            //in case there's a mongoDB error
            if (err){
                return result (err, false);
            }
            //If no user with this username is found
            if (!user){
                return result('user '+ username + 'not found', false);
            }
            return result(null,user);
        });
```

now the app.js :

```
var express = require('express');
var path = require('path');
var favicon = require('serve-favicon');
var logger = require('morgan');
var cookieParser = require('cookie-parser');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var passport = require('passport');
var session = require('express-session');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
// Initialize models
require('./models/models');
//connection to mongoDB database
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost:27017/bipperDB");

var api = require('./routes/api');
var authenticate = require('./routes/authenticate')(passport);

var app = express();

// view engine setup
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

// uncomment after placing your favicon in /public
//app.use(favicon(path.join(__dirname, 'public', 'favicon.ico')));
app.use(logger('dev'));
app.use(session({
    secret: 'super secret'
}));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(cookieParser());
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use (passport.initialize());
app.use (passport.session());

// Initialize Passport
var initPassport = require('./passport-init');
initPassport(passport);

app.use('/api', api);
app.use('/auth', authenticate);

// catch 404 and forward to error handler
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
  var err = new Error('Not Found');
  err.status = 404;
  next(err);
});

// error handler
app.use(function(err, req, res, next) {
  // set locals, only providing error in development
  res.locals.message = err.message;
  res.locals.error = req.app.get('env') === 'development' ? err : {};

  // render the error page
  res.status(err.status || 500);
  res.render('error');
});

module.exports = app;
```

And i'm getting this error :

```
throw new mongoose.Error.MissingSchemaError(name);
      ^
 MissingSchemaError: Schema hasn't been registered for model "undefined".
Use mongoose.model(name, schema)
    at Mongoose.model (C:\wamp64\www\Bipper\node_modules\mongoose\lib\index.js:362:13)
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\wamp64\www\Bipper\passport-init.js:5:21)
```

Comment: done, but now it says : Error: Cannot find module 'User'

Comment: ohh you just need to give your model file path where you defined the schema

Comment: can you be more specific please ? I didn't understand you, I'm a little bit exhausted actually ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When exporting multiple models from a single file like you are in models.js, you need to give each exported model its own exports field name.

Change your `models.js` file like this

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var User = new mongoose.Schema({
    username: String,
    password: String,
    created_at: {type: Date, default: Date.now}
});

var Beep = new mongoose.Schema({
    created_by: { type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User' },
    created_at: { type: Date, default: Date.now},
    text: String
});


//declaration of models with respective schemas
var User = mongoose.model('User', User);
var Beep = mongoose.model('Beep', Beep);

module.exports={
User:User,
Beep:Beep
}
```

Now require your model file like this

```
var model=require('path of your modelsfile/models');
```

then use as

```
model.User or model.Beep
```

Hope that will help you

Comment: okay, it works !!
-Just a little detail : I had to add var Schema = mongoose.Schema;
in my models.js
But can you actually explain me why it was not working with my previous work ?
EDIT : was it because that synthax was some "old node/express synthax" ?

Comment: When exporting multiple models from a single file like you are in `models.js`, you need to give each `exported model` its own exports field name.

Comment: Got it, next time I'll keep attention to that or just work with one file for each model. Thank your for your time Sir.